# Dealing with null objects in C#

Tags: c#

My dilemma in the code below is how to deal with a JSON object with the format below, assuming I wanted to irretarate and read the values in the currentLoc object where at least one of the objects is null, how can I read the values and avoid the null reference error in C# or blazorwasm

```
"data": {
    "assets": [
      {
    
        "currentLocs": {
          
          "fixtime": "2022-04-11T23:26:04.000+03:00",
       
          "motion_status": "ONLINE",
          
        }
      },
      {
     
        "currentLocs": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The above is the Json Object, and below are the C# classes to deserialize/serialize

```
public class Asset {

public CurrentLocs currentLocs {get; set; }
}

   public class CurrentLocs
    {
        public string unit_id { get; set; }
        public DateTime fixtime { get; set; }
        // public string location { get; set; }
        public DateTime local_fixtime { get; set; }
        public string motion_status { get; set; }
        public int gps_event { get; set; }
    } 

// finally we have a List 

  List<Asset> Listed = new List<Asset>();

// using foreach loop 

@foreach(var item in Listed){
    @item.currentLoc.motion_status
```

Comment: see, thats json not c#. Please show how you are reading this using c#

Comment: check for nulls

Comment: Why can't you just do an ordinary null check (e.g. `!= null`)? Can you share the c# code that you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use null-propagator operator `?`

```
@foreach(var item in Listed){
    @item.currentLoc?.motion_status
```

If `item.currentLocks` is null, `motion_status` will not be accessed, avoiding access to a null object

Comment: Thank you that part works very well However, Im kinda confused especially when you want to perform some overall stats for example if you wanted to get a count of all motion-status that are online within an hour... how do you avoid those curentLoc null objects

Comment: In this case you could use LINQ, and avoid the Null-Propagator filtering the results prior accessing them, here is an example: `var count = Listed.Where(x => x.currentLocs != null && x.currentLocs.fixtime <= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1)).Count(x => x.currentLocs.motion_status == "online");`
Note that `!=null` is before `x.currentLocs.fixtime `, this is because when `currentLocs` is null the second part of the expression is never reached